# Seletor de elementos: Selecionar acima do decimo elemento

Tags: jquery

tenho uma lista de divs que são preenchidas aleatoriamente na tela.
Como faço para selecionar a partir do décimo elemento repetido para cima com jquery ?

```
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
```

gostaria de selecionar com jquery somente da decima div com classe img para frente

Comment: Cara cade o que vc já tem de código? HTML/CSS/JS ? Só com seu relato não da para te responder de forma precisa....

Comment: ok eu sei so  eu ja li um monte de manual de jquery selector e nao achei nada parecido por isos nao tenho cod. se alguem souber pelo menos o nome da função eu m viro depois.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só para deixar uma resposta registrada aqui no site utilizando seletores do **jQuery** assim como é possível fazer sem uso de nenhum script apenas com **CSS**:

> Seleciona até o nono:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".img:nth-of-type(-n+9)").css("background-color","red");
})
```

```css
.img{
   border-bottom: solid 1px;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='img'>01</div>
<div class='img'>02</div>
<div class='img'>03</div>
<div class='img'>04</div>
<div class='img'>05</div>
<div class='img'>06</div>
<div class='img'>07</div>
<div class='img'>08</div>
<div class='img'>09</div>
<div class='img'>10</div>
<div class='img'>11</div>
<div class='img'>12</div>
```

> Seleciona a partir do décimo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".img:nth-of-type(n+10)").css("background-color","red");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='img'>01</div>
<div class='img'>02</div>
<div class='img'>03</div>
<div class='img'>04</div>
<div class='img'>05</div>
<div class='img'>06</div>
<div class='img'>07</div>
<div class='img'>08</div>
<div class='img'>09</div>
<div class='img'>10</div>
<div class='img'>11</div>
<div class='img'>12</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Via seletor estou quase certo que seja impossível, no entanto existe o método [`.slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) que é proprio para "filtrar" pegando somente o que deseja, exemplo:

```js
$(function () {
    var els = $('.img').slice(9);

    //Exibe os elementos
    els.each(function () {
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
<div class='img'><img src='imagem.jpg'></div>
```

Note que usei `9` ao invés de `10`, isto porque o indice começa do zero, ou seja o primeiro elemento pertence ao índice `0`, assim como segundo pertence ao índice `1` (como em um array).

Note também que `slice` permite definir o ultimo a ser pego também se definir o segundo parametro `.slice(primeiro, ultimo)`, por exemplo:

```js
$(function () {
    //Pega do terceiro até o quinto elemento
    var els = $('.img').slice(2, 5);

    //Exibe os elementos
    els.each(function () {
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='img'>1</div>
<div class='img'>2</div>
<div class='img'>3</div>
<div class='img'>4</div>
<div class='img'>5</div>
<div class='img'>6</div>
<div class='img'>7</div>
<div class='img'>8</div>
<div class='img'>9</div>
<div class='img'>10</div>
```

### Pegando os ultimos elementos com jQuery.slice

Basta aplicar o valor negativo:

```js
$(function () {
    //Pega o 10 e 9 elementos
    var els = $('.img').slice(-2);

    //Exibe os elementos
    els.each(function () {
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='img'>1</div>
<div class='img'>2</div>
<div class='img'>3</div>
<div class='img'>4</div>
<div class='img'>5</div>
<div class='img'>6</div>
<div class='img'>7</div>
<div class='img'>8</div>
<div class='img'>9</div>
<div class='img'>10</div>
```

Para limitar passe o segundo parametro, no exemplo o -2 remove os 2 ultimos elementos:

```js
$(function () {
    //Pega do quinto até o oitavo elemento
    var els = $('.img').slice(-6, -2);

    //Exibe os elementos
    els.each(function () {
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='img'>1</div>
<div class='img'>2</div>
<div class='img'>3</div>
<div class='img'>4</div>
<div class='img'>5</div>
<div class='img'>6</div>
<div class='img'>7</div>
<div class='img'>8</div>
<div class='img'>9</div>
<div class='img'>10</div>
```

Comment: e como eu faria para dar um hide somente no decimo elemento ou maior ?

Comment: @JasarOrion pode usar `$('.img').slice(9).hide()`, ou pode usar uma classe `$('.img').slice(9).addClass('minha-classe-definida-no-css-que-oculta')`, podendo ser uma classe propria ou uma classe de um FW, como Bootstrap, mas ai depende do que você usa.

Comment: show heim nao conhecia esta função muito obrigado